# Display html from JS array

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I am working on displaying an array of HTML elements from JavaScript that looks like this:

[image: Image 1]

Here is my code:

```js
function createOrderedList(items) {
  var ol = document.createElement("ol");
  items.forEach(function(item) {
    ol.appendChild(createListItem(item));
  });
  return ol;
}

function createListItem(item) {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.textContent = item;
  return li;
}
var array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
var list = array.reduceRight(function(p, c) {
  var el = createOrderedList([c]);
  if (p == null) {
    p = el;
  } else {
    el.appendChild(p);
  }
  return el;
}, null);
document.querySelector(".content").appendChild(list);
```

```html
<div class='content'></div>
```

I want it to look like the picture , for now I have something like this :
https://jsfiddle.net/ys0fp5bd/
I want make to make that the first one is equal the last one and the each next li is equal on the same level .

Comment: and what is the issue?

Comment: what is the expected output for `[a,b,c]` ?

Comment: What's that image supposed to represent; that you want each `<li>` indented more than the previous one? What have you tried to implement that requirement?

Comment: All i want is that the array sholud be displaying as a tree view